# JMeter check time a load page

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I need to make script what can get load time of page (img, css, etc)
example: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPpl1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ["Retrieve All Embedded Resources" box](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) which instructs JMeter to parse response DOM and fetch all images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc. like real browser does:

[image]

[image]

I would also suggest adding [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) as real browsers download these "resources" only once and on subsequent iterations they are being returned from the [browser cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching).